# block level I/O trace

Tags: io, block, trace

I am trying to get access to a block level I/O trace of a cloud benchmark. Ive looked at YCSB, Rain and a few other benchmarking suites, but none of them offer block/byte level logging. I am thinking of just running one of these benchmarks and using blktrace/blkparse to get the I/O trace but the problem with that is that this approach will not capture I/O requests which get fulfilled by the page cache as blktrace/blkparse works below the filesystem layer (at the block I/O layer).

Is there a cloud benchmarking suite out there which has block/byte level tracing facility? If there isnt any, then how can I get blktrace/blkparse like functionality which includes those requests which get fulfilled by the page cache (intercepting read/write system call perhaps?).

Thanks.

ps. The option of using O_DIRECT with blktrace/blkparse isnt desirable as you cant use that with already compiled programs.

Answer (score 0):

Another tool that you can check out is iosnoop http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2014-07-16/iosnoop-for-linux.html I used it to track only disk level traces but there is a bunch of other perf tools https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools which maybe can help you to fulfil your needs.